# MacPorts reinstalls nothing following migration; how to fix?

Tags: macos, macports, macos-high-sierra

I needed to install a new package using `ports` on our server.

The server was upgraded to macOS 10.13.6, but MacPorts was still two OS's behind.

So, I followed the MacPorts [migration instructions](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) to the letter.

The only thing that happened out of the ordinary is when I ran the `port -qv installed > myports.txt` command to capture my installed packages, it dumped these warnings:

```
Warning: MacPorts is configured to use an unsigned source for the ports tree. Please edit sources.conf and change 'rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/' to 'rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar'.
Warning: MacPorts is configured to use an unsigned source for selfupdate. Please edit macports.conf and change the rsync_dir setting to match macports.conf.default.
```

So, I edited the `rsync_dir` setting in `macports.conf` to match the line in `macports.conf.default`:

```
#rsync_dir          macports/release/tarballs/base.tar
```

(note: I've tried this with, and without, the `#`)

And I edited the `sources.conf` file so it reads

```
rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar [default]
```

*however*

When I get to the last step of the migration—reinstalling all of my previously installed packages using `sudo ./restore_ports.tcl myports.txt`—I get this:

```
Warning: Skipping apache2 (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping apr (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping apr-util (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping awstats (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping bzip2 (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping curl (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping curl-ca-bundle (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping db46 (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping db48 (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping db_select (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping expat (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping fetchmail (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping fontconfig (not in the ports tree)
Warning: Skipping freetype (not in the ports tree)
... about a 50 more
```

So apparently *nothing* will reinstall.

Should I just completely uninstall MacPorts and start over, or is there a simple fix?

Comment: Have you tried just copying `macports.conf.default` over your `macports.conf`? That is, eliminate all customizations.

Comment: No change. I replaced `macports.conf` with `macports.conf.default` and `sources.conf` with `sources.conf.default` and I get the same results.

Comment: Also note that I tried to install some ports manually and I get the same kind of error: `sudo port install apache2` results in `Error: Port apache2 not found`

Comment: I know you said you followed the instructions to the letter, so: you did step 3 and installed the appropriate MacPorts package for 10.13? Are you sure you're running the newly-installed version? I.e. what does `which port` say?

Comment: I downloaded and ran the [MacPorts installer package for 10.13](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.5.4-10.13-HighSierra.pkg) that I found on the [Quick Start](https://www.macports.org/install.php) page. `which port` reports `/opt/local/bin/port`

Comment: Update: I decided to ignore the warnings and I restored the original copies of `macports.conf` and `sources.conf` from a backup. I ran the `restore_ports.tcl` script again and everything seems to be downloading and building.

Comment: So what do these warnings mean, why am I getting them, and should I be concerned?

Comment: What are the relevant differences between your restored .conf files and the defaults?

Comment: @KenThomases, there are lots of differences. I don't think I've ever modified my `macports.conf` file, but it's pretty old—all of my `.conf` files are dated 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My conf files had no customizations but were dated 2012. So I made a copy of the old files and replaced each with the a copy of the .default versions that were installed during an installation of the latest release. Once this was done, the unsigned source errors will go away. Clearly the old versions of these files had outdated settings, keys, etc. So unless you had modified your conf files for specific reasons, this is an easy fix.